# Disabling text auto populating in chrome via selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Can someone guide me on how to disable text boxes from getting auto populated in chrome browser using selenium web driver?

Comment: which kinda text boxes ?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
 var options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArgument("--put-argument-here");
```

1. This argument might help:

   - "--disable-single-click-autofill"

The link below has a full list of chrome arguments

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/